# AttributeError: module 'ntpath' has no attribute 'sep'

Tags: python-3.x, windows, path

When I want to **debug** my python files which used `os.path.relpath()`，pycharm on my computer tells me：

```
collecting ... collected 0 items / 2 errors
INTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\my2ndconda\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 268, in wrap_session
INTERNALERROR>     session.exitstatus = doit(config, session) or 0
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\my2ndconda\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 321, in _main
INTERNALERROR>     config.hook.pytest_collection(session=session)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\my2ndconda\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\my2ndconda\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\my2ndconda\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 60, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\my2ndconda\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_result.py", line 60, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\my2ndconda\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\my2ndconda\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 332, in pytest_collection
INTERNALERROR>     session.perform_collect()
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\my2ndconda\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 644, in perform_collect
INTERNALERROR>     self.ihook.pytest_collectreport(report=rep)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\my2ndconda\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\my2ndconda\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\my2ndconda\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 60, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\my2ndconda\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_result.py", line 60, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\my2ndconda\lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\teamcity\pytest_plugin.py", line 328, in pytest_collectreport
INTERNALERROR>     self.report_test_failure(test_id, report)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\teamcity\pytest_plugin.py", line 223, in report_test_failure
INTERNALERROR>     self.ensure_test_start_reported(test_id)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\teamcity\pytest_plugin.py", line 186, in ensure_test_start_reported
INTERNALERROR>     self.teamcity.testStarted(test_id, flowId=test_id, captureStandardOutput=capture_standard_output, metainfo=metainfo)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\_jb_runner_tools.py", line 181, in testStarted
INTERNALERROR>     commands = _TREE_MANAGER_HOLDER.manager.level_opened(self._test_to_list(testName), _write_start_message)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\_jb_runner_tools.py", line 51, in manager
INTERNALERROR>     self._fill_manager()
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\_jb_runner_tools.py", line 59, in _fill_manager
INTERNALERROR>     from _jb_serial_tree_manager import SerialTreeManager
INTERNALERROR>   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
INTERNALERROR>   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1002, in _find_and_load_unlocked
INTERNALERROR>   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 945, in _find_spec
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\my2ndconda\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py", line 92, in find_spec
INTERNALERROR>     if self._early_rewrite_bailout(name, state):
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\my2ndconda\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py", line 193, in _early_rewrite_bailout
INTERNALERROR>     path = PurePath(os.path.sep.join(parts) + ".py")
INTERNALERROR> AttributeError: module 'ntpath' has no attribute 'sep'
```

My version of Python is 3.10.6, pytest's version is 7.1.2, and version of Windows is Windows 11 22H2 22621.674.
How to solve the problem?

---

Now I discovered this is because of conda environment, but conda list of the environment is so long and not fit to place here, please see this link:

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/9H8FNfjX3c/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed python interpreter to python venv and updated conda's version, and the problem disappeared.